# ionicFilterBar won't hide when 'Cancel' button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am developing an Ionic app. I am implementing`ionicFilterBar` in the `ionicmodal` view. I am able to filter the list by the keyword typed in but when 'Cancel' button is clicked the filter bar won't hide. And also the search field cannot be typed in when clicking somewhere else.

If anyone has some solution to this, it would be very helpful

[image]

Here is my code snippet

```
                     var filterBarInstance;
                     $scope.showFilterBar = function () {
                      filterBarInstance = $ionicFilterBar.show({
                        items: $scope.persons,
                        update: function (filteredItems, filterText) {

                          console.log(filteredItems);

                          $scope.persons = filteredItems;
                          //$scope.managements = $scope.managements
                          if (filterText) {
                            console.log(filterText);
                          }
                        }
                      });
                    };
```

Comment: can you add some more `code`,Currently unable to get the info with this.

Comment: also tell if you are using it inside a `modal` or not,and what are the `pointer events` defined within it